# Bash single quotes come from out of no where. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: bash, console

I have the following bash script which I have been looking at to generate an example fio traffic simulation command.  In the script, I take the CWD and then look for devices with a specific file name.  I then append these file names with corresponding parameters onto the command to be run but when I run the command, all of the parameters are in single quotes.
What I want and need is

```
fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB --name="output0" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfu" --name="output1" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfua" --name="output2" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfub" --name="output3" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfuc"
```

Instead what I get is .. (please take not of the single quotes.)

```
+ fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB '--name="output0"' '--filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfu"' '--name="output1"' '--filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfua"' '--name="output2"' '--filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfub"' '--name="output3"' '--filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfuc"'
```

This is the script and I've tried lots of combinations so I apologize if there is a little bit of clutter in the script.  Nothing I tried would work.  How do I script this out without having to deal with the single quotes?

```
#fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=1800GB  --rw=randrw --name="output1" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathco"
cwd=$(pwd)
x=($(ls -1 ./ | grep -i mpath))
s=" "
#echo ${x[@]}
len=${#x[@]}
len=`expr $len - 1`
#echo $len
for i in `seq 0 $len`; do s=$s\ --name=\"output$i\"\ --filename=\"$cwd/${x[$i]}\"; done
echo $s
x=`echo $s`
COMMAND=fio\ --ioengine=libaio\ --rw=randrw\ --iodepth=512\ --size=10GB\ $x
echo "$COMMAND"
$COMMAND
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not the single quotes, which actually don't exist. (They appear in bash's trace output in order to show you the arguments, because the arguments include double quotes. They are not actually part of the arguments.)

The actual problem is the double quotes, which should *not* be in the arguments. In fact, you don't want:

```
fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB \
    --name="output0" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfu" \
    --name="output1" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfua" \
    --name="output2" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfub" \
    --name="output3" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfuc"
```

What you want is the *result* of typing the above at the command-line. When you enter that line at the bash prompt, bash ends up removing the double-quotes. In the above example, the double-quotes are actually completely unnecessary. They would have been necessary had the filenames included, for example, space characters, in which case they would have served to indicate to bash that the included space characters were not argument separators. But in neither case would they be passed on to the `fio` command; bash always removes unquoted quote characters from arguments.

Quote characters which actually come from a bash parameter (like `$COMMAND`) are not unquoted quote characters. So they are not removed, and `fio` will try to use the filename `"/dev/mapper/mpathfunc"`, which is an attempt to access the directory `"` in the current working directory. Of course, that directory doesn't exist so the command will fail.

In short, it would have worked had you written:

```
for i in `seq 0 $len`; do
  s="$s --name=output$i --filename=$cwd/${x[$i]}
done
```

but only because `$cwd` and `${x/[$i]}` don't contain spaces. What you really should do is make the accumulator an array (like `x`):

```
COMMAND=(fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB)
len=$((${#x[@]} - 1))
for i in $(seq 0 $len); do
  COMMAND+=(--name=output$i "--filename=$cwd/${x[$i]}")
done
"${COMMAND[@]}"
```

Comment: What if my file names did contain spaces?

Comment: @RustyWeber: the array method will handle filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

- In Bash you can use arrays to [store commands in variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
- [you shouldn't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- Use `$(foo)` instead of `` `foo` ``.
- [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Answer (score 0):

I got what you need, you need attach each mpath* files one by one with two option (--name and --filename) to fio command, then run it.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

x=$(find $(pwd) -type f -iname "*mpath*" |awk '{printf " --name=\"output%d\" --filename=\"%s\" ", i++,$1}') 
COMMAND=" fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB $x"
echo "$COMMAND"
$COMMAND
```

Comment: That is what I need but I run your command and I get
fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB '--name="output0"' '--filename="/dev/mapper/mpathfu"'

Comment: PS your code may need to be changed a little bit..
#fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=1800GB  --rw=randrw --name="output1" --filename="/dev/mapper/mpathco"
cwd=$(pwd)
x=$(find $(pwd) -iname "*mpath*" |awk '{printf " --name=\"output%d\" --filename=\"%s\" ", i++,$1}')
echo $x
COMMAND="fio --ioengine=libaio --rw=randrw --iodepth=512 --size=10GB $x"
echo "$COMMAND"
$COMMAND

Comment: I fix one issue, can you try now?